# Optimal action-value as function of optimal value. Proof

Tags: reinforcement-learning, markov-decision-process

Currently reading through [Algorithms for Reinforcement Learning](https://sites.ualberta.ca/%7Eszepesva/papers/RLAlgsInMDPs.pdf), I think these notes are good, but there're bits that are a bit unclear, and I have few questions that I think are quite basic:

1. Definition of optimal value function definition:

Quoting the notes in the relevant bits:

> The *optimal value* $V^*(x)$ of state $x$ gives the highest achievable expected return when the process is started from state $x$. The function $V^* : \mathcal{X} \to \mathbb{R}$ is called the *optimal value function*

Later what a *stochastic stationary policy* is defined and with $\Pi_{stat}$ it is denoted the set of all stationary policies. Quoting the notes again

> The value function $V^{\pi} : \mathcal{X} \to \mathbb{R}$, underlying $\pi$ is defined by
> $$
> V^{\pi}(x) = \mathbb{E} \left[ \left. \sum_{t=0}^\infty \gamma^t R_{t+1} \right| X_0 = x \right] ,\;\; x \in \mathcal{X}
> $$

moreover we have a definition for *value function underlying an MRP

> $$
> V(x) = \mathbb{E} \left[ \left. \sum_{t=0}^\infty \gamma^t R_{t+1} \right| X_0 = x \right] ,\;\; x \in \mathcal{X}
> $$

what is the relationship between $V^*(x)$ and $V(x)$? is it by any chance

$$
V^*(x) = \sup_{\pi \in \Pi_{stat}} V^{\pi}(x)
$$

?

I assume the relationship between $Q^{\pi}(x,a)$ and $Q^*(x,a)$ is very similar, namely (assuming I'm right)

$$
Q^*(x,a) = \sup_{\pi \in \Pi_{stat}} Q^{\pi}(x,a)
$$

2. Relationship between optimal value function and optimal action-value function

> The optimal value- and action-value functions are connected in the following way:
> $$
> V^*(x) = \sup_a Q^*(x,a) 
> $$
> $$
> Q^*(x,a) = r(x,a) + \gamma \sum_{y \in \mathcal{Y}} \mathcal{P}(x,a,y)V^*(y)
> $$

I understand the meaning of the first equation, but I don't know where the second comes from. Assuming the definition of $V^*(x)$ and $Q^*(x,a)$ I guessed earlier are correct what is the actual math explaining the two equalities?

**Note** : You can look up at section 2.2. of the pdf I attached (the section is short, just in case you need more details).